# Ubuntu 16.04 - problems with MSI GE62 6QD (i7-6700hq, nvidia gtx 960m)

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I have problem with ubuntu 16.04 on MSI GE62 6QD laptop.

Specs:

```
CPU i7-6700HQ
GPU1 Intel HD 530
GPU2 NVidia GeForce GTX 960m
```

Problem:

I can't get things to work. First problem was to boot live CD. I've get freeze on loading. Adding `acpi=off` to GRUB parameters finally makes system installation possible.

After install I've noticed few issues. Automatic update get stuck on updating `unattended-upgrades`. After installation of properiaty nvidia drivers and switching to it I noticed, that Unity is not smooth. Moving windows is not smooth and tearing. I installed also intel drivers via `2.0.2 installator` from `01.org` and switched to it.

I can't shutdown/reboot system without freeze now.. I've also install `guc` and `dmc` firmware from `01.org`. System randomly shows errors `system error detected` and in `/var/crash/` I can found random applications errors (including `compiz, chromium-browser`.

Another issue is fact, that when I'm on Intel graphics and switch to TTY I can see spam of `pci bus error` messages. I found that adding `pci=nomsi` to GRUB is solving this problem and this is true - I never saw that error after this.

Next issue - writing `lspci` in terminal causes system freeze, I can't even switch to TTY.

Webcam is not installed in the system and I don't know how to do it (I cant even `lspci`, lol.).

Even on Intel graphics I feel, that system isn't so smooth as it supposed to be. (resizing windows, launching firefox, scrolling etc.)

I tried many things which I can found even on `AskUbuntu`, including:

```
many nvidia driver versions (361 to 375)
different compiz settings (refresh rate, composite, sync to vblank)
updating to kernel 4.8
intel_idle.maxcstate=1 or 0 GRUB parameter
installing system from that guide: https://medium.com/@gentra/how-to-install-ubuntu-16-04-on-msi-ge62-6qc-ae4f30f50465#.7en215j96
```

I don't know what to do and I WONT give up and back to Windows. Please, anyone can help me? I just want to use linux on new laptop..

**EDIT: After downgrade to kernel 4.4.0 at least I can shutdown/reboot system and `lspci` works**

**EDIT: I found that function key is enabling/disabling webcam - it works too. Looks like I must look only at compiz performance**

Comment: Hello, welcome to askubuntu, please simplify your question to one question per thread. I would suggest you to do this again, with a clean install and list your steps one by one, which will be easier to debug and read. Also 16.04 is using 4.4 kernel, so what do you mean by downgrade to kernel 4.4.0? Any specific version?

Comment: I tried also newer 4.8 kernel. I forgot to wrote.. Sorry :(.